# Can the Jensen Shannon Divergence be larger than the Cosine Distance for a pair of distributions?

Tags: geometry, statistics, euclidean-geometry

I've been looking for an example where the Jensen-Shannon Divergence is larger than the Cosine Distance, but I can't find any. I'm using Excel's Solver to look for possible solutions, but I wonder if there is a proof that says that it is impossible.

**JS Divergence:**

$${\rm JSD}(P \parallel Q)= \frac{1}{2}K_L(P \parallel M)+\frac{1}{2}K_L(Q \parallel M)$$

where $K_L$ is **the KL Divergence**:
$$D_\text{KL}(P \parallel Q) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} P(x) \log\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)$$

and $M$ is the average probability between $P$ and $Q$:

$$M=\frac{1}{2}(P+Q)$$

**Cosine Distance:**

$$\text{Cosine Distance} = 1 - \text{Cosine Similarity}$$

Cosine Similarity:

$$\text{Cosine Similarity} = {\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{Q} \over \|\mathbf{P}\| \|\mathbf{Q}\|} = \frac{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{P_i  Q_i} }{ \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{P_i^2}}  \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{Q_i^2}} }$$

Comment: It's better if you type out the definitions here, than make users go offsite to see them.

Comment: I included the definitions and removed the external links. Thanks.

Comment: You can get legible displayed equations by enclosing the in `$$` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example: if you take $\textbf{P} = [0.2, 0.8]^\top$ and $\textbf{Q} = [0.05, 0.95]^\top$, you get

- $JSD(\textbf{P}\|\textbf{Q}) \approx 0.0273$
- $\text{Cosine Distance} (\textbf{P}, \textbf{Q}) \approx 0.0184$.

Comment: Did you use an analytical method to find your counter-example?

Comment: I just wrote a Python code that tries distributions of the form $P=[a, 1-a]$ and $Q=[b, 1-b]$ for $a, b\in \{0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 0.9, 0.95, 1\}$. Each time, it computes the JSD and Cosine Distance and checks which one is largest. It turns out that the inequality you were asking about gets violated for multiple combinations of $a$ and $b$.